# iOS background image height width in Xcode for 1x, 2x, 3x

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add a background image to iOS app. I am not sure about the dimensions of the image for the 1x, 2x, 3x. I want the background image working for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice graphic that displays all the screen sizes and background image sizes (courtesy of [Reign Design](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/preparing-for-the-new-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus-screen-sizes/)):

[image]

Comment: What about 5.8'' iPhone X?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://makeappicon.com/) link to get proper dimensions of an image for your app  :)

just upload a high quality image and it returns 2 collections that can be used for different devices of IOS and Android apps